# Linux application in livecode

Tags: livecode

Spell Check is a default application in Linux. With the help of that application, can we check the spelling of a text field while users enter data?

Comment: A spell checker isn't always a default in all linux distros...

Comment: With the help of Spell Check application, can we check the spelling of a text field while users enter data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some (or many?) Linux distributions contain a command line utility that is called `spell`. If you run this with words as parameters, you need to press return a second time, but if you use a file as a paramater, you don't need to press return again. This means that a solution could be:

1. write the text of a field to a file
2. run the command line utility from LiveCode's `shell` function with the file as parameter
3. parse the result returned by the `shell` function

Before you try this, open your terminal on Linux and type `spell`. Press enter to see if the command is recognised. If yes, then the script below should work.

This script writes the text of a field to a file, does a spell check on the file and returns the incorrect words to LiveCode. I haven't tested the script and you may have to tweak it a little.

```
function spellCheck theText
     // works on Linux only
     if the platform is "Linux" then
          // remove everything that isn't a word
          put replaceText(theText,"[^\w]","") into myWords
          // write clean data to a temporary file
          put the tempName into myTempFile
          put myWords into url ("file:" & myTempFile)
          // call spell with shell
          put "spell" && myTempFile into myShell
          // only return the incorrect words
          put line 2 to -1 of shell(myShell) into myCorrections
          // return the incorrect words to calling handler
          return myCorrections
     else
          // this isn't Linux
          return "error"
     end if
end spellCheck

//theField is the short name of a field
on checkField theField
     // call above function
     put spellCheck(the text of fld theField) into myWords
     // myWords should now contain the incorrect words
     if myWords is not "error" then
          lock screen
          // parse incorrect words and mark them in the field
          repeat with x = 1 to number of words of field theField
               if myWord is among the lines of myWords then
                    // an incorrect word has been found and is marked red
                    set the textColor of word x of fld theField to red
               end if
          end repeat
          unlock screen
     end if
end checkField
```

Usage: `checkField shortNameOfTheField`

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Can you please explain what is happening here.

Comment: I have added and introduction to the answer and comments to the code.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I am using ispell then I how I change this code

Comment: Just have a look at the ispell output and change my script accordingly.

Comment: You may not need to use a file, but you will need to experiment with that. I don't have ispell installed.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. I made some changes in your coding after that it's works                                                                                                                     // parse incorrect words and mark them in the field
          repeat with x = 1 to number of words of field theField
             put the word x of field theField into myWord
             if myWord is among the lines of myWords then